# Is it possible to make a magnetic material only out of neutrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin

Since its the spin of electrons that makes iron magnetic (along with the convenient arrangement of the atoms in the crystal structure) by arranging neutrons in the right way is it possible to make a substance only made of neutrons magnetic?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic nuclei can have magnetic moments so yes you can make a magnet out of nucleons. You seem to be looking for something bigger involving only neutrons. This would be a neutron star. [Neutron stars have very large magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Magnetic_field).

Comment: Is that because of the neutrons or the minuscule number of charged particles left?

Comment: I don't know this, but it should be possible to estimate the neutron spin contribution so their is probably an answer. This is worthy of a new question.